# When using box-sizing:border-box in *Chrome*, why does <input type="text"> render differently from <input type="password">

Tags: css, google-chrome

Have a look at 2 inputs that have the same CSS styles applied, the first is type="text", the second is type="password"
[Screenshot showing input padding & height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5BJv.png)

The total height (padding-top + content-height + padding bottom) is smaller than declared height (30px) for both inputs, however, the text input renders it's contents visibly. The password input looks empty (and cursor does not show).

I have since fixed the padding-top/-bottom values, but that was after a long struggle trying to debug why password fields weren't "working". I am merely curious to find out why the behavior is different

Link to [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/67FyL/), or have a look at the HTML + CSS:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="hello"/>
<input type="password" value="hello"/>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="datetime"],       input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="date"], input[type="month"], input[type="time"], input[type="week"], input[type="number"], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="color"] {
    height: 30px;
    line-height:30px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="datetime"], input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="date"], input[type="month"], input[type="time"], input[type="week"], input[type="number"], input[type="email"], input[type="url"],     input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="color"] {
  padding: 16px 11px 16px 11px !important;
  font-size:14px !important;
  color:#333 !important;
  border: 1px solid black !important;
}
```

Comment: Is the fiddle supposed to show something different between them, because they look the same in Chrome.

Comment: @j08691 the second input is not supposed to _look_ blank! I expect the password glyphs to be visible as well. Also, this is in Google Chrome, I've checked with Firefox it looks similar (like you said). I had tagged this question as 'google-chrome', but I ought make it clearer that this is chrome-specific in the title

Comment: In Chrome it's not blank.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/22rlVhd.png

Comment: @j08691 d'oh: you're right again: it's blank in _Chromium_ (34.0.1847.116 Ubuntu) http://i.imgur.com/4mDwT2M.png. I opened up in Chrome (35.0.1916.153) proper and it looks the same

Looks like I've been bitten by a Chromium bug.

Answer (score 0):

It's a defect of your CSS.

According to your CSS, the content height of <input> is 30px - 16px - 16px - 1px - 1px = -4px.  So, there is no space to show content.